# Check if environment variable or its containing path doesn't exist

Tags: bash, shell

I want to check if the environment variable MY_DIR or its containing path doesn't exist.

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

# If $MY_DIR or its containing path doesn't exist
if [ ! $(env | grep -q ^MY_DIR=) ] || [ ! -d "$MY_DIR" ]; then
  echo "not existing"
  # set it
  export MY_DIR="$PWD"
fi
```

Comment: What do you mean by "its containing path"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the empty string cannot name an existing directory, you don't need to worry if `MY_DIR` is set or not; just check if its (possibly nonexistent) value names a directory.

```
if [[ ! -d $MY_DIR ]]; then
    export MY_DIR=$PWD
fi
```

There's also no need to check specifically if `MY_DIR` is in the environment. While it is possible to have a shell variable that is not an environment variable, it is *not* possible to have an environment variable that is not also a shell variable[0], nor is it possible to have a shell variable with the same name as an environment variable but a different value (an environment variable is simply a shell variable with its export attribute set.)

[0] OK, technically you could inherit an environment variable whose name is not a valid shell identifier. Let's just ignore those, shall we? :)

Comment: You should use double quotes around `"$MY_DIR"` and `"$PWD"`.

Comment: Congrats, 50K !! Good answer also : )

Comment: Ha, didn't notice I was that close! I can retire now.

Comment: @KeithThompson Parameter expansions are not subject to word-splitting or pattern expansion inside `[[...]]` or on the right-hand side of assignment statements. They don't hurt, so you can use them if you want, but I like to avoid them when they are truly unnecessary. (But I do like to hear if I've missed a corner case that *does* make them necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it can be made with this code:

```
if [[ ! -d "$MY_DIR" ]]; then
    export MY_DIR="$PWD"
fi
```

Or with a one-liner:

```
[[ ! -d "$MY_DIR" ]] && export MY_DIR="$PWD" || echo "MY_DIR already set"
```

The above code echoes a message saying when is already set, if is not needed you can try with this:

```
[[ ! -d "$MY_DIR" ]] && export MY_DIR="$PWD"
```